# Weird behavior of Raspberry Pi GPIO ports

Tags: gpio, pi-2, rpi.gpio

I am trying to manipulate the GPIO pins using python. I have used many examples from the web. However, I noticed weird behavior of GPIO ports.

1) If I make a port high, it becomes high momentarily and then again it turns low.

2) If I initialize a port for output then it stays high regardless of the value we set.

Can anyone please help me with that? I am using RPi 2.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
sleep(10)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
sleep(10)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
sleep(10)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
sleep(10)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to switch your GPIO pins?

Comment: Are you connecting anything to the ports? Please show your circuit.

Comment: I am posting the code. Give me few minutes. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: It's difficult to fault that. Not much going on! Per David's comment above, is anything connected to the pins? There have been a lot of previous questions where things like [cobbler boards](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2029) have been connected back to front, leading to much confusion.

Comment: Have you tried any other libraries like gpio zero? This problem sounds strange though. Have you hooked an oscilloscope up?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using GPIO. HIGH/Low try using 1 for high and 0 for low.